# Unknown black rectangle on top of keyboard in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

What is this black rectangle space that pops on top of the keyboard when clicking on a text form field? The issue only occurs when on an Android device using the web browser. It also seems very inconsistent as you can see on the GIF, sometimes it occurs, sometimes it does not. I could not figure what it is because there were no error logs occurring when doing remote debugging. In the remote debugging, the keyboard displays on the middle(the black thing) and there is some white space on the bottom (see second picture below). Would you know what could be causing this? This app is running on an older version of Flutter by the way which is 2.10.5 so was this a known issue? I've added the Scaffold code below and TextFormField for reference. If someone can point me to the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

[image: This is how the black space above it looks like]

[image]

This is the code for the main Scaffolding:

```
return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(Images.backgroundImg),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)),
            child: PageLayout(
              header: NotAuthorizedHeader(
                isBackPress: false,
              ),
              child: LoginLayout(
                  onLogin: props.login,
                  loading: props.isAuthenticating,
                  authMessageError: props.authMessageError),
              getMoreList: () {},
              loadingMore: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Then this is the text form field snippet:

```
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Text(
      placeholder,
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: AppColors.gray3),
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 10),
    TextFormField(
      validator: validator,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      obscureText: obscureText,
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: AppColors.gray10,
          fontSize: 13,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: AppColors.gray9,
        hoverColor: AppColors.gray9,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
      ),
      onEditingComplete: () {},
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
        onSubmit();
      },
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem after further testing. Apparently the black rectangle was being caused by the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` property of the `Scaffold` on mobile web browsers. So the fix was to set the `Scaffold` property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` when the platform is on web.